# How to set minimize application to system notification tray in xaml vb?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

How to set minimize application to system notification tray in xaml vb? I want when I click minimize app icon it automatically throw the application to system tray.

I have this code in my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Image x:Name="minimizeapp" Source="/minus.png" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

And then I have this code in my `MainWindow.xaml.vb`:

```
Public Sub newInitialize()
   InitializeComponent()

   notifyIcon = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
   notifyIcon.Icon = New System.Drawing.Icon("./Resources/Chromatix-Aerial-Web.ico")
   notifyIcon.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub minimizeapp_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles minimizeapp.MouseDown
   Me.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
   Me.Hide()
   notifyIcon.Visible = True
End Sub
```

When I click the minimizeapp icon, I get an error on the `notifiIcon.Visible = True` line.

The error is:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> notifyIcon was Nothing.

Do you know what am I missing? Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in Grid_Loaded.

```
Private Sub Grid_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    notifyicon = New NotifyIcon()
    notifyicon.Icon = New Icon("./Resources/Chromatix-Aerial-Web.ico")
    notifyicon.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub minimizeapp_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles minimizeapp.MouseDown
    Me.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
    Me.Hide()
    notifyicon.Visible = True
End Sub
```